# Mysql inner join queries usage

Tags: mysql, inner-join

These are two tables: one category table and another product table

category table

```
id     name
1      mealA
2     mealB
```

product table

```
id     name     category_id ( refer to category table)
1     chicken     1,2
2     fries      1
3     tomato     2

SELECT * FROM product INNER JOIN category on product.category_id = category.id where category.name='mealA'
```

i am a bit shocked to find that the ***chicken*** is displayed as the result(by other ppl's code). It is my first time i know i can `inner join` comma seperated column directly with other column.

I did research online, seem there is another answer by using `find_in_set` in mysql, why inner join is able to do this, can anyone help to explain?

Comment: Does this also work for mealB? The reason I ask is that the "=" comparison in MySQL may compare the 1=1,2  and get true (1=1) but probably won't get 2=1,2 as true (2<>1). http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you compare an integer column (`category.id`) with a string column (`product.category_id`), the string value is converted to an integer before performing the comparison. When converting a string to an integer, it ignores everything after the initial numeric part, so the string `1,2` is converted to the number `1`.

So `chicken` will match `mealA`, but it won't match `mealB` because `2` is after the `,`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is working as you think it is; it shouldn't.

I'm guessing that `product.category_id = category.id` is converting `product.category_id` to an `INT` for comparison, thus taking the `1` from `'1,2'` which matches the `1` from the `category` table.

I much prefer a properly defined HAS_MANY relation (one row per category relation) to a CSV field, especially for reference. Anything else opens up a world of complexity.